# SQL Compare tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

i have two tables which have identical schema, there are two columns in the table which i want to compare the results and get unique rows on those that do not exist as below.

Table name: flow

| Employee | Dateinoffice |
| --- | --- |
| John | 15/09/2021 |
| Joane | 15/09/2021 |
| Rob | 15/09/2021 |

Tablename: console

| Employee | Dateinoffice |
| --- | --- |
| John | 15/09/2021 |
| Joane | 15/09/2021 |
| Rob | 15/09/2021 |
| Rob | 16/09/2021 |

the results of the query should be

| Employee | Dateinoffice |
| --- | --- |
| Rob | 16/09/2021 |

Reason is because this row exists in console table but does not exist in flow.

Comment: `EXCEPT` can be used, if your dbms supports it.

Comment: @Ardian . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE  (
    Employee nvarchar(100),
    Dateinoffice datetime
)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE  (
    Employee nvarchar(100),
    Dateinoffice datetime
)

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES ('John', '2021-09-15'),('Joane', '2021-09-15'),('Rob', '2021-09-15')
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES ('John', '2021-09-15'),('Joane', '2021-09-15'),('Rob', '2021-09-15'),('Rob', '2021-09-16')
```

-- Your query would be like this

```
select * from @table2
except
select * from @table1
```

-- If you want to only matched records

```
select * from @table2
intersect
select * from @table1
```

---

**Remember: In the" except " statement, the order of the queries is important.**

In details look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can use `full join` to get rows that are missing from either table:

```
select coalesce(f.employee, c.employee) as employee,
       coalesce(f.dateinoffice, c.employee) as employee
from flow f full join
     console c
     on f.employee = c.employee and f.dateinoffice = c.dateinoffice
where f.employee is null or c.employee is null;
```

If you specifically want rows in `console` that are not in `flow`, you can use `left join` or `not exists`:

```
select c.employee, c.dateinoffice
from console c left join
     flow f 
     on f.employee = c.employee and f.dateinoffice = c.dateinoffice
where f.employee is null;
```

Comment: i want rows that are not on the other table, so all rows that exit in console which are not in in flow, i  get the following when i run: `select c.employee, c.dateinoffice
from console c left join
     flow f 
     using (employee, dateinoffice)
where f.employee is null;` _Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'using'.

Completion time: 2021-09-15T12:01:05.6730751+01:00_

Comment: @Ardian . . . I see that you added a database tag after I answered.  SQL Server does not support the standard `USING` clause so you have to be explicit about the `ON` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different perspective, try this

```
select * from console 
where Employee+'-'+convert(varchar, Dateinoffice, 23) 
not in (select Employee+'-'+convert(varchar, Dateinoffice, 23) from flow)
```